# ARMA(1,1) Unique Solution

Tags: arma

Assume that we have a white noise process. When you try to fit an ARMA(1,1) model on it (clearly wrong model but bear with me):

$y_t=ay_{t-1}+b\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$

you will end up with a variety of different $(a,b)$ where $a+b=0$ depending on where the optimizer will start.

Of course I rather get $a=b=0$ to slap me in the face to show me this is not the right model.

Is there any way to constrain the optimization so that I get the $(0,0)$ solution?

Thanks

Comment: Since I presume you'd only want the constraint to be applied when the process is white noise, the answer is evidently no; you'd need to know the process is white noise in order to activate the constraint, in which case there's no point in doing the estimation (and therefore no point in having the constraint.)  Also note that you won't in general end up with $\hat{a}+\hat{b}=0$ from an estimation routine, due to noise in the series.

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you write, you obtain estimates $(\hat a, \hat b)\; : \;\hat b = -\hat a$, your estimator is telling you that

$$y_t=ay_{t-1}-a\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t = a(y_{t-1}-\epsilon_{t-1})+\epsilon_t$$

But

$$y_{t-1}-\epsilon_{t-1}= ay_{t-2}-a\epsilon_{t-2} = a(y_{t-2}-\epsilon_{t-2})$$

and so

$$y_t - \epsilon_t=   a^2(y_{t-2}-\epsilon_{t-2})  $$

Setting $z_t = y_t - \epsilon_t$ we have

$$z_t = a^nz_{t-n}$$

So if the $\hat a$'s you obtain are $< |1|$, the estimator tells you that $z_t=y_t - \epsilon_t \rightarrow 0$ (oscillating perhaps) and so, essentially, that $ y_t = \epsilon_t$, i.e. it's ...telling the truth.

If $\hat a=1$ then the estimator tells us that

$$y_t -\epsilon_t =  y_{t-1} -\epsilon_{t-1} =... = y_{t-n} -\epsilon_{t-n} \Rightarrow \sum y_t = \sum\epsilon_t\Rightarrow y_t = \epsilon_t $$
...again telling the truth.

Finally, if  $\hat a> |1|$, the estimator is telling us that the process, explodes, either oscillating or exponentially, which clearly is against the visual you have (since the process is actually a white noise). So again the estimator tells us the truth by loudly signalling "what a useless model did you make me estimate".

I really don't see any need to complicate matters by constraining  the optimization procedure.

Comment: See my comment in response to the OP; you won't in general wind up with $\hat{b} = - \hat{a}$.

Comment: Of course not exactly. But if you run it for 15,000 points you get pretty close.

Comment: @Alecos: This is just an exercise. The point I am trying to illustrate is that most of the time we don't know the model beforehand like in this example. It would have been good if we had more tools for automation without human intervention.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc In non-experimental settings, we never know the model. But my answer does not pre-supposes that you know the model. The estimates themselves tell you that $y$ is white noise.

Comment: @Alecos: You deduce that with a long analysis of the coefficients. Sometimes it is not white noise but a very small AR or MA component. In that case "a + b = very small number". It would have been useful if we could reach a canonical form, where either a or b is nonzero in such situations, or both zero in case of white noise.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Indeed, but I think that you are asking our estimators to perform miracles, and on their own.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Foggily, I _think_ that I remember reading about how, when two coefficients are non-existent, most estimators instead of shrink both estimates to zero, tend to "offset" the one with the other. But I am not sure whether this was a casual observation from experience, or whether it was theoretically backed somehow.